# Android Expansion file won't trigger onDownloadStateChanged?

Tags: android

I'm trying to make my app download an expansion file. Here's my code so far.

```
public class main extends Activity implements IDownloaderClient {

TextView tv1;
Button mcButt;

@Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);

  //////////
  tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

  // Check whether the file have been downloaded.
  String mainFileName = Helpers.getExpansionAPKFileName(this, true, 1);
  boolean fileExists = Helpers.doesFileExist(this, mainFileName, 32921796L, false);

  if (!fileExists) {

   Intent launcher = getIntent();
   Intent fromNotification = new Intent(this, getClass());
   fromNotification.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
   fromNotification.setAction(launcher.getAction());

           if (launcher.getCategories() != null) {
                for (String cat : launcher.getCategories())
                { fromNotification.addCategory(cat); }
           }

   PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, fromNotification, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

   try {

    int result = DownloaderClientMarshaller.startDownloadServiceIfRequired( this, pendingIntent, ExpansionFileDownloaderService.class);
    if (DownloaderClientMarshaller.NO_DOWNLOAD_REQUIRED != result) {

        // implement Downloading UI.
        tv1.setText("Need to download.");

     return;
    }

   } catch (Exception e) { 
    Log.e("apk-expansion-files", "NameNotFoundException occurred. " + e.getMessage(), e);
   }
  }

  tv1.setText("Downloaded!");


 }


///////////////////////////////////////////////////


@Override
public void onServiceConnected(Messenger m) {
    tv1.setText("onServiceConnected: " + m.toString() );
}

///////////

@Override
public void onDownloadStateChanged(int newState) {
    tv1.setText("onDownloadStateChanged: " + String.valueOf(newState) );
}

////////////

@Override
public void onDownloadProgress(DownloadProgressInfo progress) {
    ProgressBar mPB = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

    progress.mOverallTotal = progress.mOverallTotal;
    mPB.setMax((int) (progress.mOverallTotal >> 8));
    mPB.setProgress((int) (progress.mOverallProgress >> 8));
    tv1.setText(Long.toString(progress.mOverallProgress * 100 / progress.mOverallTotal) + "%");
    tv1.setText(Helpers.getDownloadProgressString(progress.mOverallProgress,progress.mOverallTotal));

}
```

}

The file does download fine, but it does not trigger onDownloadProgress or onDownloadStateChanged during or after download.

What comes to mind, is that DownloaderClientMarshaller need to be somehow connected with IDownloaderClient which is implemented into the activity...

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: You probably need to set the event listeners?

Comment: obviously yes... how do you think I should link it to DownloaderClientMarshaller ?

Comment: I can verify that I do not get onDownloadStateChanged responses either

Answer (score 3):

You should create and stub and connect it to the context. Then, the events will be sent to your IDownloaderClient.

```
if (DownloaderClientMarshaller.NO_DOWNLOAD_REQUIRED != result) {
  downloaderClientStub = DownloaderClientMarshaller.CreateStub(this,
                     YourDownloaderServiceClass.class);
  downloaderClientStub.connect(this);       
}
```